# Cakephp And Mysql Tinyint(1) returning Null

Tags: mysql, cakephp, tinyint

So here is my problem.

I have a field in my database called maillist with the type tinyint(1). Using phpmyadmin i inserted into some fields the values 0's and 1's.
When i read from the database here is the array returned.

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [maillist] => 
        )

)
```

Where the maillist should be 0 or 1 because in my database all the fields on the maillist are filled.
So i decided to change the type on the field to tinyint(4) and that fixed the problem are here is the returned array.

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [maillist] => 0
        )

)
```

Please note that i did not change any values i just changed the type from tinyint(1) to tinyint(4).
Although the problem is fixed i would like to know what might have caused this behavior ? do i have a lack of understanding in retrieving data using cakephp ? Did i miss something important ? Or this might have been a bug.

Comment: mysql used to use tinyint(1) to simulate `bit` fields. When mysql finally added `bit` fields, some mysql drivers got confused by the new type and just made its values null, and did so by specifically checking for a `tinyint(1)`.

Comment: Well it is not really of an overhead the difference between tinyint(4) and tinyint(1), so i will avoid the mess up and use tinyint(4), thank you loads for your reply!

Comment: Marvan: really bad idea. the one will be interpreted as boolean, the other (your tinyint4) would be an integer. so please don't try to find your own wrong solution to a nonexistent problem.

Comment: I am not interpreting it as boolean, here is what i am doing  'value' => $user['User']['maillist'] just to set the checked on a radio button, but i will keep that in mind.

Comment: tinyint1 = boolean = 2 definite states. If you want to have more than two states (enumeration, list, ...) then you should use tinyint(2/3) or int(x). just for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `var_dump($array)` instead of `pr($array)`

`pr()` does not show variable types and will never show booleans as there is no `true` or `false` character.

http://codepad.viper-7.com/tUvSTu

Comment: The problem was not in pr(), i only did used it to see the values returned. I was doing echo $user['User']['maillist'] and getting nothing.

Comment: echo is the same as pr() / print_r(). You need to use var_dump() to see boolean types, especially false. Look at the paste.

Comment: or use `debug()` in cake >= 2.x this will show even false/true properly.

Comment: 'maillist' => boolean false great ^^ i got your point ^^ And saw my mistake ! i want the value to be 1 or 0 to set the value of a radio button ! Thanks for your reply.